# C++11 std::this_thread::sleep_until() hangs when compiled with GCC 4.8.5

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4.8

Consider the following program:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - std::chrono::seconds(10));

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with GCC 4.8.5, it will hang. When compiled with GCC 4.9 and above or clang3.4 and above, it returns immediately,

Why would it hang? As I understand, GCC 4.8.5 fully supports C++11 standard.

Comment: what do you think `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` represents? hint: subtracting 10 from that number will not change much

Comment: @Fureeish they're probably asking if something in the standard changed that affects the behavior of `sleep_until`.

Comment: @Fureeish Question edited. It was unclear on what is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug that was fixed in gcc 4.9.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58038

> When using sleep_until() I get an bug with unsigned long scalar representations of a duration. If this duratoiin is in past, then you get an overflow in the length of the argument for sleep_for(). This causes an almost infinte sleep, instead of a fast return.

Answer (score 5):

This case is considered by the Standard and according to it `sleep_until` should move on. Seems its a bug in GCC 4.8.5

[[33.2.4  Timing specifications]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/thread.req.timing)

> The member functions whose names end in _until take an argument that specifies a time point. 
>   These functions produce absolute timeouts. Implementations should use the clock specified in 
>   the time point to measure time for these functions. Given a clock time point argument Ct, the 
>   clock time point of the return from timeout should be `Ct + Di + Dm` when the clock is not 
>   adjusted during the timeout. If the clock is adjusted to the time Ca during the timeout, the 
>   behavior should be as follows:
>
> - if Ca > Ct, **the waiting function should wake as soon as possible**, (...), since the timeout
>     is already satisfied. [ Note: This specification may result in the total duration of the wait decreasing when measured against a steady clock. — end note ]
>     — if `Ca < Ct`, ...